# Can not handle NLua crash

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

I'm trying to use lua scripts on my C# application, but I'm having problems to run different scripts, when I run 3~4 scripts I keep getting this exception:

[image]

As you can see I'm "catching" the AccessViolationException exception, just in case:

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
            public void ExecuteAsync(MyLuaThread thread)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (Monitor.TryEnter(ObjLocker, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                            if (ScriptRunning[thread.name])
                            {
                                var result = lua.DoString(thread.code);
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }
                        catch (AccessViolationException e4)
                        {
                            thread.errors.Add(time() + " - Access Error - " + e4.Message);
                            print("(" + thread.name + ") Access Error - " + e4.Message);
                        }
                        catch (NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException e)
                        {
                            thread.errors.Add(time() + " - Script Error - Line: " + e.Message.Substring(e.Message.IndexOf(":")));
                            print("(" + thread.name + ")Line: " + e.Message.Substring(e.Message.IndexOf(":")));
                        }
                        catch (Exception otherEx)
                        {
                            thread.errors.Add(time() + " - Other Error - " + otherEx.Message);
                            print("(" + thread.name + ") Access Error - " + otherEx.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                            Monitor.Exit(ObjLocker);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

I created this small project to show you guys the error happening. Just add 3~5 threads and start them, it shouldn't take more than 5 seconds to the crash happen.

Small Project link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fyk8tblff7v5wa/SmallLuaTest.rar

Comment: I don't see the problem,  you have the debugger set up to break on an exception,  so it does. If you want to see your catch work,  just hit the continue button.

Comment: threads + lua doesnt sound so good. Is each thread having its own lua state or are all threads editing the same lua state locklessly?

Comment: @RonBeyer That's the point, it doesnt hit the catch block, and if Im not debbuging it, just running the program it crashs.

Comment: @Rochet2 I talked to the NLua creator about that, he said NLua is thread-safe and it should work, he will take a look in this small project soon, anyway, if I create different Lua states it doesn't crash, but I lose the point of my software, where scripts can share variables and functions between them.